# CollectionViewController UILongPressGestureRecognizer only work when setting delay and minimum

Tags: ios, ios9

I can not understand why I have to set

```
longGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.3;
longGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = true;
```

Before the `action` is being fired, do you know why?

```
longGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
longGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.3;
longGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = true;
[self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:longGesture];
```

Comment: delaysTouchesBegan sets to avoid the triggering of  collectionview didHighlightItemAtIndexPath methos. Also minimumPressDuration not required, because default is 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code. You don't have to set this longGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.3
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr 
       = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                     initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    lpgr.delegate = self;
    lpgr.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
    [self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
}

-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        return;
    }
    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.collectionView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];
    if (indexPath == nil){
        NSLog(@"couldn't find index path");            
    } else {
        // get the cell at indexPath (the one you long pressed)
        UICollectionViewCell* cell =
        [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        // do stuff with the cell`enter code here`
    }
}
```